# apt-get giving an error

Tags: apt

When I try to run update, upgrade or install I always get an error:

```
Setting up initscripts (2.88dsf-34) ...
Can't exec "insserv": No such file or directory at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 391.
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing initscripts (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
configured to not write apport reports
                                      Errors were encountered while processing:
 initscripts
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Previously I tried to upgrade and got a huge error log with this kind of errors:

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up initscripts (2.88dsf-34) ...
Can't exec "insserv": No such file or directory at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 391.
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing initscripts (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
configured to not write apport reports
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initscripts
Error in function: 
Setting up acpi-fakekey (0.141-1) ...
Can't exec "insserv": No such file or directory at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 406.
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing acpi-fakekey (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
Setting up kmod (9-2) ...
Can't exec "insserv": No such file or directory at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 406.
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing kmod (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
Setting up dbus (1.6.8-1) ...
Can't exec "insserv": No such file or directory at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 406.
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing dbus (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox:
 rhythmbox depends on dbus; however:
  Package dbus is not configured yet.
```

What's wrong?

Comment: It is seems that this is giving the problem `sysv-rc : Depends: insserv (> 1.12.0-10) but it is not going to be installed` How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, here:
**Run this in the terminal**

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/insserv/insserv /sbin/insserv
```

Then run the usual

**It solved my problem below**, I hope it fixes yours.

```
Setting up initscripts (2.88dsf-34) ...
Can't exec "insserv": No such file or directory at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 406.
 update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing initscripts (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initscripts

ln -s /usr/lib/insserv/insserv /sbin/insserv
```

Then I ran synaptic again

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up initscripts (2.88dsf-34) ...
```

I have another error now though

```
E: /var/cache/apt/archives/
gstreamer0.10-plugins-good_0.10.31-3+nmu1ubuntu1_i386.deb: 
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10/libgstcamerabin.so',
which is also in package gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad:i386 0.10.23-7
```

So I marked gstreamer-bad-plugins for removal in synaptic. So far, so good.
**Update:** It finished with no errors. :D

Comment: The soft link fixed my issue also...